# GNU Make silent by default

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to suppress command echoing by default from within the `Makefile`?

I know that running `make` in `--silent` mode will do it, as will prefixing every command with `@`.

I'm looking for a command or stanza I can include **inside** the Makefile, saving the trouble of littering everything with `@` or having the user silence everything manually.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you define the target `.SILENT:`, then make will not echo anything.  It's usually best to guard the definition, so you can easily turn it off:

```
ifndef VERBOSE
.SILENT:
endif
```

Now by default, make will print nothing, but if you run `make VERBOSE=1`, it will print.

Note that despite the statement in the manual claiming that `.SILENT` is obsolete -- if properly guarded, it is generally much better (more useful and flexible) than `@`.

Comment: An even simpler method than using `ifndef` is just to write `$(VERBOSE).SILENT:`.  Now if `VERBOSE` is empty you get the `.SILENT` target, but if you set `VERBOSE` to any non-empty value it will be disabled (define a completely different target that means nothing to make).  This is also portable to other versions of make, if that matters to you.

Comment: It should be noted that you make sure you don't put this at the top of your Makefile. Otherwise it will try to execute the target when you set `VERBOSE` to any non-empty value. Might be obvious to some users, but I spent a few minutes wondering why I was getting error `make: Nothing to be done for '1.SILENT'.` when executing `VERBOSE=1 make` thinking it would perform my usual default target.

Comment: To clarify: there's nothing wrong with putting `.SILENT` guarded by `ifndef` at the top of the `Makefile` as described in this answer.  Per https://gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html, targets that start with a `.` will not become the default.  However, @MadScientist's suggestion of using `$(VERBOSE).SILENT` should *not* be first.  I personally wouldn't use it for that subtle caveat and because I think it's much less clear.

Comment: @MadScientist Or, if you really want to be succinct (at the expense of obscuring intent),`.SILENT$(VERBOSE):` would avoid the placement problem.

Comment: The idea of `.SILENT$(VERBOSE)` is slightly less reliable because GNU Make reserves _every_ symbol that starts with `.[A-Z]` for possible future expansion.  Obviously it's highly unlikely that GNU Make will choose to reserve the target name in the exact way that user choose to set `VERBOSE`.

Answer (score 38):

You can add `--silent` in the [`MAKEFLAGS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion) variable at the beginning of your `Makefile`:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --silent

all:
    echo foobar

.PHONY: all
```

And you will have:

```
$ make
foobar
```

Comment: I'm using GNU make 4.3, and .SILENT does not seem to work any more. However, this trick (adding the --silent flag) still works.

Comment: This answer guides people to use more clear and readable ways. Thank's

Comment: @ErikSchnetter Strange, I'm also using GNU make 4.3 and adding a `.SILENT` target correctly suppresses command echoing.

Comment: Note this method won't work with older versions of GNU make, where modifying MAKEFLAGS inside the makefile isn't as well supported.  It also is less portable: the `.SILENT` target is specified by POSIX but `--silent` is not (although `-s` is), and it's not specified by POSIX what happens if you modify `MAKEFLAGS` inside the makefile.

Answer (score 13):

According to [GNU Make's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html), you can use special target `.SILENT`.

Note that the manual says that:

> .SILENT is essentially obsolete since ‘@’ is more flexible.

But it seems to work as expected. The following code silences the `all` target:

```
.SILENT:

hoge:
    echo hoge
```

The following example silences only the `hoge` target:

```
.SILENT: hoge

hoge:
    echo hoge

fuga:
    echo fuga
```

Comment: tell that to cmake

Comment: FYI this statement regarding "essentially obsolete" was removed from the manual back in 2016.  It was never really true.