# Makefile to do nothing

Tags: linux, makefile

I'm testing a proect, and due to testing purposes, it must include a Makefile, and the first test command will be 'make'. However I don't need the makefile to do anything. The problem is that if I leave it empty, it prints a line in the shell:

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I need it to **not** print **anything** when called in the shell - not even an empty line (again, due to tests format which I don't control). Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define an empty target

```
 Nothing:
```

the `make` command will tell

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'Nothing'.
```

Then, just add a .SILENT target

```
# A makefile
Nothing:

all: twist again

.SILENT:
```

See link [GNU Make silent by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005166/gnu-make-silent-by-default)

Answer (score 13):

This should do it (i.e. nothing):

```
null:
    @:
```

Comment: @user1794469: Really? Which version of Make are you using?

Comment: My bad, I had the spacing off for the second line; it works as stated.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following complete makefile:

```
all :
.PHONY : all
```

Comment: It says : `make : Nothing to be done for 'all'`. Define the .SILENT target instead
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005166/gnu-make-silent-by-default

Comment: @blz It does print that, however, `make` succeeds now. With no defined targets it fails.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Could you give an example - I really know nothing about make.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks, but I need a makefile that prints nothing, not even an empty line

Comment: @blz Run `make` with `-s` flag, alternatively `make &> /dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I've edited to include answer for future lookers

Answer (score 3):

This recipe do nothing.

```
.DEFAULT:
    @echo -n ""
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU Make, `-s` will suppress printing which commands are executed:

```
   -s, --silent, --quiet
        Silent operation; do not print the commands as they are executed.
```